# Open Berkeley DB version 1.85 in Python on a non BSD system

Tags: python, bsddb

How can I open Berkeley DB 1.85 file in Python on a non BSD system (Ubuntu, RHEL)?

```
$ file 1.db 
1.db: Berkeley DB 1.85 (Hash, version 2, native byte-order)
```

The code i am trying to run:

```
    import bsddb

    cur_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    db_file_path = os.path.join(cur_dir, '1.db')
    db = bsddb.hashopen(db_file_path, 'r')
    for k, v in db.iteritems():
        print k, v
```

This is the exception:

```
  File "....py", line 22, in handle
    db = bsddb.hashopen(db_file_path, 'r')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 364, in hashopen
    d.open(file, db.DB_HASH, flags, mode)
bsddb.db.DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- __db_meta_setup: /.../1.db: unexpected file type or format')
enter code here
```

`pip` doesn't want to install `bsddb185` module:

```
$ pip install bsddb185
Downloading/unpacking bsddb185
  Running setup.py egg_info for package bsddb185
    Didn't find db.h with HASHVERSION == 2
No files/directores in /.../build/bsddb185/pip-egg-info (from dependency_links.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, a colleague of mine helped me to build the module from source.

Download the source here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb185

Then:

```
cd bsddb185/db.1.85/PORT/linux/
make
cd ../../..
python setup.py install
```

Comment: This doesn't work with 1.1 as there's no directory `db.1.85/` in the source root.

Answer (score 0):

The docs recommend that this module is deprecated in favour of bsddb.db.  If you're sticking with bsddb, they also have the comment, "The bsddb module requires a Berkeley DB library version from 4.0 thru 4.7."

docs: http://docs.python.org/library/bsddb.html

Hope some of this points in the right direction, sorry I couldn't be more helpful.